# HTML List Hide Top level

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list like this,

1. Key1

   - Belgium
   - France
2. Key2

   - Germany
3. Key3

   - Italy
   - USA

How can i hide only the outer lists (key1, key2, key3)
Hide not remove because the sorting is done on the Keys only.

Resault should be

- Belgium
- France
- Germany
- Italy
- USA

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work as you require.

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>Key one
        <ul>
            <li>Belgium</li>
            <li>France</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>Key two
        <ul>
            <li>Germany</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>Key three
        <ul>
            <li>Italy</li>
            <li>USA</li>
        </ul></li>
</ol>​
```

CSS:

```
ol > li {
    font-size: 0;
}

​ol > li li {
    font-size: 16px;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rXqYB/1/).

Comment: The demo doesn't work, or your code doesn't work? Bearing in mind I was guessing your HTML.

Comment: what is see something like this
i still can see the arrow, it seems that there is css format the list therefore i can still see the bullets but not the "key" word

Comment: Show me what you see. Show me the relevant HTML and the CSS for that HTML. Put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can work with what you've got, rather than guessing what you're doing. Help **us** to help *you*.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>Key1
        <ul>
            <li>Belgium</li>
            <li>France</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Key2
        <ul>
            <li>Germany</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Key3
        <ul>
            <li>Italy</li>
            <li>USA</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("ol ul li").each(function() {
        $("ol").append("<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>");
    });
    $("ol > li:has(ul)").hide();
});
```

Comment: I forgot to say that i have a very limited HTML, JS programming skills
i guess this function is Jquery?
I copied this function in the script section but nothing seems to be happining

Comment: Yes, that is jQuery. Add this line within your `<head></head>`: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>
<li>Key one
    <ul>
        <li>Belgium</li>
        <li>France</li>
    </ul></li>
<li>Key two
    <ul>
        <li>Germany</li>
    </ul></li>
<li>Key three
    <ul>
        <li>Italy</li>
        <li>USA</li>
    </ul></li>
```

​

CSS:

```
ul li {
    text-indent: -3000px;
    display:block;
}
ul li ul li {
    text-indent: 0px;
}
```

Hope it works, haven't tested it... but should work with text-indent: -3000px;

EDIT: Change text-indent:none; to text-indent:0px;

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to previous answers, if you have access and can control how the HTML looks, you could instead create the list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li sort="Key1">Belgium</li>
    <li sort="Key1">France</li>
    <li sort="Key2">Germany</li>
    <li sort="Key3">Italy</li>
    <li sort="Key3">USA</li>
</ul>
```

You could then use the custom `sort` attribute to sort rather than the outer lists.